# Подключение curl для авторизации через соц сети

Tags: yii

Пытаюсь подключить eauth (авторизация через соц сети) и получаю:

```
You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.
```

П.С. php_curl.dll и php_openssl.dll в php.ini раскомментил.

Код исключения:

```
if(!function_exists('curl_init') && !in_array('https', stream_get_wrappers())) {
    throw new ErrorException('You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.');  
...
```

На localhost не работает. Залил на сервер - все ОК.

Answer (score 1):

По идее этого в файле настроек

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

должно хватить за глаза и за уши. + перезапуск Apache.

ps. ну раскомментировал ты эти строки, а сами-то Dll в папке расширений есть?

Comment: @Shrek, да проверял. все есть. может еще что-то нужно сделать?

Comment: скинь **phpinfo();** может не подключилось

Comment: @Shrek, определенно. на всей странице нет слова curl.

п.с. как скинуть? весь?